# how to skip entry point when having multiple entry points in mlflow project

Tags: python, mlflow

I'd like to be able to skip some entry points specified in my `MLProject` depending on some arguments or results from earlier entry points.

How can I skip an entry point and continue to the next one without exiting the entire MLflow project?

My files are as follows:

```py
#MLproject
name: ...
conda_env: ...
entry_points:
  main:
    command: "python3 a.py"
  secondary:
    command: "python3 b.py"
```

```py
#a.py
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("skipping a.py.")
    sys.exit(0)
```

```py
#b.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("reached b.py.")
```

I expected this to exit `a.py` and proceed to `b.py`, but it seems that `sys.exit(0)` kills everything, judging by the output of `mlflow run .`:

```
INFO mlflow.projects.utils: === Created directory /var/folders/bm/dbpln1sj3c1cn4p1gnvvp8s80000gn/T/tmpz1u4wkqq for downloading remote URIs passed to arguments of type 'path' ===
INFO mlflow.projects.backend.local: === Running command 'source /Users/pme/opt/anaconda3/bin/../etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate mlflow-19a070d548e136c3ce89701ba50b4a6b5f1d047b 1>&2 && python3 a.py' in run with ID '0ee84f73fc044603b3e625d8029337de' === 
skipping 'a.py'.
INFO mlflow.projects: === Run (ID '0ee84f73fc044603b3e625d8029337de') succeeded ===
```

Answer (score 2):

That isn't how entry points are used. Entry points are commands that can be executed within the project, so you have to call them whenever they're needed. Wether the `mlflow run` command-line tool, or the `mlflow.run()` Python API.  (They are not called automatically)
When you run `mlflow run` command, you can also tell the name of the entry point to use with `-e`, otherwise, its value defaults to `main`.

So what's the solution? You can either change the command to use the `-e` parameter as said in the [docs](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#cmdoption-mlflow-run-e)

```
mlflow run . -e secondary
```

or you can change the `MLproject` file to this and change the `main` entry point (default entry point).

```
#MLproject
name: ...
conda_env: ...
entry_points:
  main:
    command: "python3 b.py"
  secondary:
    command: "python3 a.py"
```